# .htaccess Remove index.php remove query and leave string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been working on an .htaccess file. The url I started with was,  `www.example.com/index.php?page=pagetitle`. I want the Link to only show `www.example.com/pagetitle`.

So far the only thing in my .htaccess file removes the `index.php`.

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.(php|html?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I sadly don't have the knowledge to create these codes on my own.

Thank you in advance.

I will also be editing this question as I figure more of this out, from support of other people etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try these rules:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It looks like it works, thank you very much! I'll accept you answer when it lets me :-)